# How many times to flip a coin

Tags: statistics

At least how many times you need to flip a coin in order to get heads more than 3 times with probability 85%

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  With $X$ the number of heads thrown, $P(X>3)=1-P(X≤3)$.

Comment: Yeah but i dont know how to estimate n later. for example in when I calculate the factorials with n

Comment: Well, you could use the normal approximation to get a sense of what $n$ ought to be, but that's overkill.  Just guess...the computation is fast.

Answer (score 1):

After flipping a coin $N$ times, find the probability $P$ of getting at least four heads. It is one minus (probability of getting no heads + pr. one heads + two heads + three heads).
Now assume $P=0.85$ and solve the above to find $N$.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:**

I am not sure if this problem is supposed to give you practice with
factorials, with binomial distributions, or with normal approximations
(as mentioned by @lulu). So I have no idea what approach you are
expected to take.

In R statistical software, I get that $n = 11$ will work and $n = 10$ is not
enough.

```
 n = 3:30;  p3 = 1-pbinom(3, n, .5)
 min(n[p3>.85])
 ## 11
 # Checking
 1 - pbinom(3, 10, .5)
 ## 0.828125
 1 - pbinom(3, 11, .5)
 ## 0.8867188
```

Maybe it is enough just to compute it for $n = 10$ and $n = 11$
(and claim to be a good guesser). In guessing, I suppose it helps to know that the *average*
number of tosses to get 3 heads is $3(1/.5) = 6.$ (see the 'negative binomial
distribution'.)